# Surface Pro 3, dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04, How to use volume keys in grub os selection?

Tags: dual-boot, surface

Bluetooth keyboard won't work in Grub, and connecting an USB keyboard only to boot up Ubuntu is very annoying. So, how can i use the volume up/down keys to select the os?

Answer (score 1):

One (hacky) option is to boot into ubuntu by default and then use [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu) to boot into windows from there.

Personally that's what I'd do since it's quick and simple and I don't need to get to windows that often.

Another option would be to install a wrapper around grub that supports touch screen. I've heard that rEFInd is good but I haven't tested it on my SP3. [Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760875/any-downside-to-using-refind-instead-of-grub) a post talking about it, and here's a quick install guide:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
```